# youtube iframe player not firing events after change iframe parent container

Tags: javascript, typescript, youtube-api

In my application, I need to change the container in which the YouTube iframe is located. After changing the container, the state change events (onStateChange) are not firing. However, the ready event (onReady) is called every time when parent changed.
I tried to add "addEventListener" to the onReady event handler, but it does not work and event not firing.
For example:

```
export class YouTubePlayer
{
    private player: YT.Player;
    private ready: boolean = false;

    public Init(): void
    {
        (<any>window).onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () =>
        {
            console.log("VideoPlayer onYouTubeIframeAPIReady");

            this.player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '800px',
                width: '600px',
                playerVars: { 'modestbranding': 1, 'disablekb': 1, 'showinfo': 0, 'autoplay': 0 },
                events: {
                    'onReady': (ev: YT.PlayerEvent) =>
                    {
                        if (this.ready)
                        {
                            //It's not working for me. Events not firing after change parent container
                            ev.target.addEventListener("onStateChange", (evTwice: YT.PlayerEvent) =>
                            {
                                console.log("VideoPlayer: I'm alive!!!");
                            });

                            this.player.addEventListener("onStateChange", (evTwice: YT.PlayerEvent) =>
                            {
                                console.log("VideoPlayer: I'm alive too!!!");
                            });

                            return;
                        }

                        this.ready = true;

                        setInterval(() => { this.player.loadVideoById("lArqtUE2w3o"); }, 5000);
                    },
                    'onStateChange': (ev: YT.PlayerEvent) =>
                    {
                        //Events not firing after change parent container
                        console.log("VideoPlayer change state: " + ev['data']);
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        console.log("VideoPlayer init");
        let script = window.document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        window.document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

I do not understand why events stop being called and how to get them back

Comment: Note: your code is suspiciously constructed. Never pass unbound methods as callbacks (your `onPlayerReady` method will throw when called by the YouTube API) , defining properties with `var` is a syntax error, and your type assertion implies you didn't even bother to install `npm:@types/youtube`.

Comment: This is only example code. And install @types/youtube can't help me(

Comment: @UserName were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @ShahidSyed No. I set player on top level component and not change its location. If needed, i change "display" property for hide/show.